# Sitemesh mapping multiple decorators won't work as expected

Tags: jsp, sitemesh

I am trying to decorate a page with multiple decorators using sitemesh 3.
The problem occurs when I add more pages, some of the pages gets decorated by another decorator leading to not properly decorated page.

Here is what I am trying to do:

- Decorate `/` and `/login` with 2 decorators
- Decorate `/welcome` with 2 different decorators

The `sitemesh3.xml` look like this so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemesh>
    <mapping>
        <path>/</path>
        <decorator>/decorator1.jsp</decorator>
        <decorator>/decorator1-2.jsp</decorator>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <path>/login</path>
        <decorator>/decorator1.jsp</decorator>
        <decorator>/decorator1-2.jsp</decorator>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <path>/welcome</path>
        <decorator>/decorator2.jsp</decorator>
        <decorator>/decorator2-2.jsp</decorator>
    </mapping>
</sitemesh>
```

The problem is that `/welcome` gets decorated by `decorator1` and `decorator1-2`

Can someone explain what did I missed here?

BTW, can I use multiple `<path>` inside mapping to map multiple locations on one or more decorators or each path must be declared separately.

I know that I can use `/*` to map all pages but what if I want something like:

```
<mapping>
    <path>/admin/*</path>
    <path>/manage/*</path>
    <path>/secured/admin/*</path>
    <decorator>decorator.jsp</decorator>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, the answer is YES. You can add multiple `<path>` in `<mapping>`, all paths will be decorated.
Back to your first question, if you decorate / or /* with some decorators, they will be applied all page. This means, if you want specifically decorate pages, please do NOT use / or /*. Below configurations come from my current project.

```
<mapping path="/*" decorator="/WEB-INF/decorators/menu.ftl"/>

<mapping>
    <path >/catalog/*</path>
    <path >/attribute/*</path>
    <decorator>/WEB-INF/decorators/product_menu.ftl</decorator>
    <decorator>/WEB-INF/decorators/menu.ftl</decorator>
</mapping>

<mapping>
    <path >/member/comment*</path>
    <decorator>/WEB-INF/decorators/comment_menu.ftl</decorator>
    <decorator>/WEB-INF/decorators/menu.ftl</decorator>
</mapping>
```

As you can see, all pages are decorated by menu.ftl, and we also have some specific decorator for other pages.